# Find in Cell Array structure in Matlab, error: Expected one output from a curly brace or dot indexing expression

Tags: matlab, find, cell

I have a cell Array called 'MPI{216,10}', containing strings or matrix in different cells. In column 10 (MPI{:,10}), there is a matrix with three column. I want to find the matrices which sum of their third column is zero. So, I wrote:

```
find(sum(MPI{:,10}(:,3)) == 0)
```

but I am getting this error:

```
Expected one output from a curly brace or dot indexing expression, but there were 216 results.
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Are the matrix rows equally sized?

Comment: Yes, they are all in equal sizes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use parentheses indexing for getting a slice of a cell array, then apply a function on each cell by `cellfun`

```
find(cellfun(@(x) sum(x(:,3)), MPI(:,10))==0)
```